# Does Runaan's apply on hit?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was trying out Jinx with Runaan's Hurricane in a game (cause I saw in the patch that the Runaan's bolts now look like Jinx rockets.  Hey explode like them too.  The question I had is, do the bolts on Runaan's apply on hit effects, specifically Jinx's rocket AOE damage?

Comment: The Runaan's was applying HUGE damage when it hit multiple enemy champions.  More than anything I'd expect, which led me to believe this.

Comment: This isn't duplicate, since this is preseason and runaans was changed along with a ton of other crap guys

Comment: It's a duplicate, because in the preseason changes, they didn't change whether it applies on-hit effects. It has always done that (except for one-use on-hit effects like Sheen which only apply to your primary target). The rocket thing is just a special change they made for Jinx in 5.24. In 5.23, they also added that the bolts are icy bolts when Ashe's Q is active.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Runaan's bolts can apply on-hit effects

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runaan's_Hurricane)

It's ridiculously OP on jinx.